# openCV combining an image to another image on given coordinates

Tags: c++, image-processing, opencv

i wrote a face & eye detection code
next step is put an image to the coordinates of the detected eye (for ex: eye
patch, eye glasses)
i couldn't find the function to combine the source frame and the image I want to add

any suggestions

thanks

Comment: +1...I am onto the same path as you were can you please help me out with how have you added the two image masked image with camera image....

Answer (score 4):

You can use **cvCopy with a mask** to do this. If the the images do not have the same height and width set the ROI of the destination image before using cvCopy.

See OpenCV documentation:

- [cvCopy](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/operations_on_arrays.html?highlight=cvcopy#cvCopy)
- [cvSetImageROI](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/operations_on_arrays.html?highlight=roi#cvSetImageROI)